# AJAX with jsp and servlet

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

I have this jsp page with a form ie.

```
<form name="contact" action="">  
            <fieldset>  
                <div id="res"></div>
                <label for="name" id="name_label">Name</label>  
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />  
                <label class="error" for="name" id="name_error">This field is required.</label>  

                <label for="email" id="email_label">Return Email</label>  
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />  
                <label class="error" for="email" id="email_error">This field is required.</label>  

                <label for="phone" id="phone_label">Return Phone</label>  
                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />  
                <label class="error" for="phone" id="phone_error">This field is required.</label>  

                <br />  
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send" />  
            </fieldset>  
        </form> 
<div id="res"></div>
```

and a ajax for the button

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "processServlet",
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#res').wrap(data);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
```

and in the servlet i have string that have html tags

```
 String te="<div class=\"input-control text\" \n" +
"                                         data-role=\"datepicker\" \n" +
"                                         data-week-start=\"1\"\n" +
    "                                         data-format='m/d/yyyy'\n" +
"                                         data-effect='slide'>\n" +
"                                        <input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Date purchased\" 
          name=\"DATEPURCHASED\" id=\"DATEPURCHASED\">\n" +
     "                                        <button class=\"btn-date\" disabled></button>\n" +
```

"                                    ";

```
        out.println(te);
```

the servlet returns a date picker to the jsp page. and when the datepicker is displayed in the jsp page the datepicker doesnt seems to work? what am i doing wrong?do i need to return a whole html file to the page?it looks like they are not sharing the css and js of the main jsp page.

Comment: Any reason for using  $('#res').wrap(data); rather than $('#res').html(data)?

Comment: @developerwjk i have searched the net to how to insert elements in div, any difference between wrap and html?

Answer (score 0):

`$('#res').html(data)` will set the `innerHTML` of the div to the contents of the variable `data`.

`$('#res').wrap(data)` is trying to wrap the contents of `data` around the div.

If you want to wrap divs around all your paragraphs, use [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

```
$( "p" ).wrap( "<div></div>" );
```

If you want to put something in a div, use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: is there any difference about accessing the css and js files of the main page?

Comment: JS and CSS file included in the page you are accessing with Ajax won't come along. You have to include your CSS and JS in the main page.

Comment: for my understanding of your answers the main page have all the import of css and js, and the response of the servlet would just be a "div" for example?am i right?

Comment: the wrap and html gives the same result